# Bug: page_fans_city query causing 500 internal server error

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-insights

Some people seem to have the same error I am seeing; if I query using FQL to get the insights metric page_fans_city, I get a 500 Internet Server Error response. An identical query for page_fans_country or other metric works fine.

How does one log a new bug? Can't find anything to tell me how...

FQL: Select metric,value from insights where object_id=######### AND metric='page_fans_city' AND end_time=end_time_date('2012-07-15') AND period=period('lifetime')

Can anyone confirm this is a bug...and log the bug?